# how to say 60 seconds with currentTimeMilis()

Tags: java

I'm trying to type out a code that outputs random words from a list, the user must type back as many words as possible before 60 seconds has elapsed I am using `currentTimeMillis()` to keep track of time so this is difficult for me to figure out I tried the code below and it said `6000000000000` is too large of a number but when I output the current/start time, it output `1512409897444` so this doesn't make sense to me.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(currentTime);
System.out.println(startTime);
while (startTime <= 6000000000000)
{
    (etc.  ect.)
}
```

Comment: 60 seconds, in milliseconds, is 60000

Comment: 60 seconds = 60000 milli seconds, currentTimeMillis returns the number of milli seconds since 1.1.1970.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is compare the current time against the time you started and check if their difference is below 60 seconds, aka 60000 milli seconds:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) <= 60000) {
    // still under 60 seconds...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a value that increases from an "epoch".  You must subtract two time values to determine the amount of time that has elapsed.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long elapsedTime = 0;
while (elapsedTime <= 60000) {
    // etc, etc, etc
    elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have already answered you have to subtract the starting time to the current time to determine if the difference is greather than 60 seconds (60,000 milliseconds). Also you can use [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) to get a more readeable code:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) <= 60) {
    //do stuff
}
```

### EDIT

If you are wondering why `6000000000000` gives you an error and the result of `currentTimeMillis()` (1512409897444) doesn't, is because they are different datatypes: int (32 bits) vs long (64 bits). The literal value `6000000000000` is interpreted as an int value which is greather than the max supported 32-bit signed int value (`2,147,483,647`) and the compiler doesn't allow that. It would work if you use a long literal instead `6000000000000L` (note the L at the end).  Signed long's max supported value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. The result of `System.currentTimeMillis()` is a long value hence `1512409897444` is valid. Read [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for further information.